# Remove whitespace from start and end of String without trim()

Tags: java, string

How to remove whitespace from the start and end of a `String` without using the `trim()` method?

here is my code

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String line = " Philippines|  WNP|Naga  |Camarines Sur|Naga Airport  ";

                //System.out.println(line);

                int endIndex = line.indexOf("|");
                String Country = line.substring(0, endIndex);
                line = line.substring(endIndex + 1);

                int endIndexCountry = line.indexOf("|");
                String Code = line.substring(0, endIndexCountry);
                line = line.substring(endIndexCountry + 1);

                int endIndexCode = line.indexOf("|");
                String City = line.substring(0, endIndexCode);
                line = line.substring(endIndexCode + 1);

                int endIndexCity = line.indexOf("|");
                String State = line.substring(0, endIndexCity);
                line = line.substring(endIndexCity + 1);

                System.out.print("Code:" + Code + "____");
                System.out.print("Country:" + Country + "____");
                System.out.print("State:" + State + "____");
                System.out.print("City:" + City + "____");
                System.out.println("Airport:" + line+ "____");
    }
}
```

and my output looks like this

```
Code:  WNP____Country: Philippines____State:Camarines Sur____City:Naga  ____Airport:Naga Airport  ____
```

I need to look like this(without whitespaces)

```
Code:WNP____Country:Philippines____State:Camarines Sur____City:Naga____Airport:Naga Airport____
```

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with Swing. 2) ***..Why*** without using `trim()`?

Comment: am edit my code @AndrewThompson check now

Comment: If you don't want use trim method from the box by some reason, you need to implement your own trim method. Is it what you need help with ?

Comment: yes, I need to remove the first white space and last white spaces. I can use only indexof() , Substring() and replace() methods

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove whitespace from the start and end of a String without
>   using the trim() method?

You can do it using a combination of regex patterns and `String::replaceAll`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "      Hello       ";
        System.out.println("Before: " + str + "World!");
        str = str.replaceAll("^[ \\t]+", "").replaceAll("[ \\t]+$", "");
        System.out.println("After: " + str + "World!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before:       Hello       World!
After: HelloWorld!
```